# Shiny environment to use for renderImage

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

In shiny I am building a list of boxes and inside each there is a `renderImage` like this:

```
images = ["i1.png", "i2.png", "i3.png"]
for(i in 1:3){
  print(i)
  q_list[[i]] = box(
    width = 12,
    status = "primary",
    renderImage({
      print(i)
      img_path = images[i]
      print(img_path)
      list(src = img_path, alt = "This is alternate text")},
      deleteFile = F)
  )
}
```

unfortunately the boxes do not seem to register the `i` in the loop. In the above, the first `i` it prints is correct (1-2-3). But the second `i`, the one inside `renderImage` prints as 3 and the `img_path` is `i3.png`. Do I need to put another environment to `renderImage` for this to work?

as requested in the comment here is a minimal example. the dahsboard displays the same graph (i3.png) in the 3 boxes:

```
rm(list = ls(all.names = TRUE))
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinybusy)
library(shinyjs)
options(shiny.error = browser)
options(shiny.fullstacktrace = TRUE)
options(shiny.trace = TRUE)

images = c("i1.png", "i2.png", "i3.png")

ui = dashboardPage(
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
  body = dashboardBody(uiOutput("module_body")),
  header = dashboardHeader(disable = T)
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  imgs_fct = function(){
    im_list = list()
    for(i in 1:3){
      print(i) # prints correctly
      img_path = images[i] # prints correctly
      print(img_path)
      # store each box in im_list
      im_list[[i]] = box(
        width = 12,
        status = "primary",
        renderImage({
          print(img_path) # prints "i3.png"
          list(src = img_path, alt = "This is alternate text")}, deleteFile = F)
      )
    }
    return(im_list)
  }

  output$module_body = renderUI({
    theitems = tabItem(tabName = "xxx", fluidRow(column(width = 8, offset = 2, id = "form", imgs_fct())))}
  )
}

# run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a full working app or dashboard code? That would make it much clearer what's going on. As a general rule though, Shiny doesn't like `for` loops. You may find that using `lapply` works as then each `renderImage` happens in a separate function call.

Comment: @mr-putter: thank you. see edit. I don't think it matters if its a for loop or lapply. why would it?

Comment: See this for example: https://chasemc.github.io/post/the-subtleties-of-shiny-reactive-programming-lapply-and-for-loops/... Essentially the render needs to happen in its own environment which happens in the function call of an lapply but not a for loop. My understanding of this in shiny is a bit sketchy though so I might be explain this badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, if you use `lapply` in the `imgs_fct` function, this will work as expected, with each plot rendered as expected rather than just the final plot for all of them. Note that `images` is a vector of file paths to the images, so have assumed they're in the same directory as your Shiny app code:

```
  imgs_fct = function(){
    lapply(images, 
           function(x) {
             box(
               width = 12,
               status = "primary",
               renderImage({
                 list(src = x, alt = "This is alternate text")}, deleteFile = F)
             )
           })
    }
```

The reason this works and a `for` loop doesn't is because the counter you use to iterate (here `i`) is shared across all the `renderImage` calls as they're evaluated in the same environment (as they're within the same loop). What happens is, the calculation runs, and then when Shiny then tries to resolve any reactive dependencies at the end of this process, all the `render` functions share the same reference `i` which at this point is equal to 3, and so all render with the same image.

In contrast, with `lapply`, each `renderImage` is in a separate function call and hence are evaluated in a separate environment, where each function has as an argument a different image file path. Hence, these render separately as you expect. You could probably wrap the contents of your `for` loop in `local({})` but I personally like the `lapply` approach as it seems more 'R'-y.