# Getting the same plot for different subsets of data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create a dynamic set of plots that changes according to the number of factors in the data. The problem is that shiny display the last evaluated plot multiple time.
I tried to create a simple version of my original code to give a reproducible example.
I generate a number of normal distributions according to the slider input, each distribution is recognized by a factor value (A, B, or C). Depending on the number of distributions selected, I want to plot each distribution alone, but as I said I get the last distribution in the loop repeated multiple times.

```
    max_plots <- 3

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=3)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_sim <- reactive({
    if(input$n == 1){
      y <- rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 0,sd = 1)
      x <- rep("A",1000)
      f <- "A"
    }else if(input$n == 2){
      y <- c(rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 10,sd = 2.5),
              rnorm(n = 1000,mean = -10,sd = 2.5))
      x <- c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",1000))
      f <- c("A","B")
    }else{
      y <- c(rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 20,sd = 2.5),
            rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 30,sd = 2.5),
            rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 40,sd = 2.5))
      x <- c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",1000),rep("C",1000))
      f <- c("A","B","C")
    }
    d <- list(data = data.frame(X=x,Y=y),fac = f)
    d
  })
  
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
  for (i in 1:input$n) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    data <- data_sim()$data %>% filter(X == data_sim()$fac[i])
    local({
      my_i <- i
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(density(data$Y))
      })
    })
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This may be due to you using a `for` loop. If you replace this with `lapply` or `purrr::map` you may find that works: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65052325/shiny-environment-to-use-for-renderimage/65061047#65061047) for a similar issue

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. the discussion actually helps me find a working solution. I just moved the part of data extraction into the local() block and it works.

Comment: If you have found the answer to the problem you can self answer your own question by including the answer below. It might help somebody else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution that I found is to put the data extraction part inside the local block. Here is the working example.

```
max_plots <- 3

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),
  
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("n", "Number of plots", value=1, min=1, max=3)
  ),
  
  mainPanel(
    # This is the dynamic UI for the plots
    uiOutput("plots")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_sim <- reactive({
    if(input$n == 1){
      y <- rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 0,sd = 1)
      x <- rep("A",1000)
      f <- "A"
    }else if(input$n == 2){
      y <- c(rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 10,sd = 2.5),
              rnorm(n = 1000,mean = -10,sd = 2.5))
      x <- c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",1000))
      f <- c("A","B")
    }else{
      y <- c(rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 20,sd = 2.5),
            rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 30,sd = 2.5),
            rnorm(n = 1000,mean = 40,sd = 2.5))
      x <- c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",1000),rep("C",1000))
      f <- c("A","B","C")
    }
    d <- list(data = data.frame(X=x,Y=y),fac = f)
    d
  })
  
  # Insert the right number of plot output objects into the web page
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    plot_output_list <- lapply(1:input$n, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
    # to display properly.
    do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
  # are visible on the web page.
observeEvent(input$n,{
  for (i in 1:input$n) {
    # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
    # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
    # of when the expression is evaluated.
    
    local({
      my_i <- i
      data <- data_sim()$data %>% filter(X == data_sim()$fac[my_i])
      plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
      
      output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
        plot(density(data$Y))
      })
    })
  }
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```